# Acessing the video stream from a IC-3030 camera

Tags: linux, ip-camera

I am going to purchase an [IC-3030](http://www.edimax.com/en/produce_detail.php?pd_id=358&pl1_id=8&pl2_id=91) camera. I want to access the video stream and download it as it happens, but not by using the Edimax-supplied video utility, as the computer will be running Linux.

I am unable to find in the user manual whether I can access the stream directly or not.

How can I access the video stream directly from an Edimax IC-3030 camera?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The camera has RTMP streams which can de directly accessed using *e.g.* `ffmpeg`.

Answer (score 0):

The video stream for this camera can be accessed at:

`"http://ip-address-of-Camera/mjpg/video.mjpg"`

or

`"http://login:password@ip-address-of-Camera/mjpg/video.mjpg"`

Source: [How to directly access the video stream of Edimax camera](http://www.edimax.us/html/Faq/How%20to%20view%20the%20video%20stream%20of%20Edimax%20Camera%20directly.pdf)